# Department change management utility

Tags: performance, c

I was wondering on how to make the execution time faster. Is there a way to make it faster with this method or do I need to make with another method? If someone have any solution please help me. because I'm really struggling with this and I tried many different things and my lecture said that this code's execution time is still too long. This program is about a person who wants to change departments. But if he wants to change departments, there must be another person from that department that want to move to the other department. For example,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node{
    int a;
    int b;
    struct Node *next;
}Node;

typedef struct Result{
    int info;
    struct Result *next;
}Result;

Node *createNode(int a, int b){
    Node *p = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    p->a = a;
    p->b = b;
    p->next = NULL;
    
    return p;
}

Result *createResult(int res){
    Result *p = (Result*)malloc(sizeof(Result));
    p->info = res;
    p->next = NULL;
    
    return p;
}

void initialize(Node **F, Result **R){
    (*F) = NULL;
    (*R) = NULL;
}

int check(Node **F, int a, int b){
    if((*F) == NULL){
        (*F) = createNode(a, b);
        return 0;
    }
    
    Node *temp = (*F);
    Node *before = NULL;
    while(temp != NULL){
        if(temp->b == a && temp->a == b){
            if(before == NULL){
                (*F) = temp->next;
            }else{
                before->next = temp->next;
            }
            free(temp);
            return 1;
        }else{
            before = temp;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
    
    before->next = createNode(a, b);
    
    return 0;
}

void addResult(Result **R, int res){
    Result *p = createResult(res);
    Result *temp = (*R);
    
    if(temp == NULL){
        (*R) = p;
    }else{
        while(temp->next != NULL){
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = p;
    }
}

void showResult(Result *R){
    Result *temp = R;
    
    if(temp == NULL){
        return;
    }else{
        while(temp != NULL){
            printf("%d\n", temp->info);
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    int a, b, i, N, count;
    Node *First;
    Result *Res;
    initialize(&First, &Res);
    
    while(scanf ("%d", &N) != EOF){
        count = 0;
        First = NULL;
        for(i=0; i<N; i++){
            scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
            count += check(&First, a, b);
        }
        addResult(&Res, count);
    }
    
    showResult(Res);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Input and Output example:

```
7 //The amount of people who wants to change
1 2 //The person who wants to change dept from where to where (1)
35 66 //The person who wants to change dept from where to where
100 500 //The person who wants to change dept from where to where(2)
2 1 //The person who wants to change dept from where to where (1)
2 3 //The person who wants to change dept from where to where(3)
500 100 //The person who wants to change dept from where to where(2)
3 2 //The person who wants to change dept from where to where(3)
3 //The total of how many can change from dept A to dept B
3 //The amount of people who wants to change
100 200 //The person who wants to change dept from where to where
200 400 //The person who wants to change dept from where to where
400 1 //The person who wants to change dept from where to where
```

Comment: Note: `scanf ("%d", &N)` returns `0, 1, EOF`.  Better to check against the desired result of 1 than one of the two undesired results in `while(scanf ("%d", &N) != EOF){`.  Use `while(scanf ("%d", &N) == 1){`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thanks for the advice, but it still very slow

Comment: @BCdotWEB Okay, Thank you so much!

Comment: `addResult()` does not need a `while` loop.  Instead add to the beginning of the list.

Comment: "Is there a way to make it faster with this method or do I need to make with another method?" --> Yes there is a way. How slow is this one?  What is the goal?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica right now, its 1.996 s. It has to be 0.628s maximum

Comment: 1.996s is hard to believe with `N==7` as in the example.  So I suspect the example test code does not reflect supplied times.  What is `N`, 7000, 7 million, 7 billion?  What is the large `N`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have undefined behaviour here:

> ```
> Node *createNode(int a, int b){
>     Node *p = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
>     p->a = a;
>     p->b = b;
>     p->next = NULL;
>     
>     return p;
> }
> ```

When `malloc()` fails (and it will, according to Murphy!) it returns a null pointer.  Dereferencing such a pointer (with `->`) is Undefined Behaviour.  We need to avoid that:

```
Node *createNode(int a, int b)
{
    Node *p = malloc(sizeof *p);   /* N.B. don't cast! */
    if (p) {
        p->a = a;
        p->b = b;
        p->next = NULL;
    }
    return p;
}
```

Also, we need to account for the fact that `createNode()` can return null, when we call it, and possibly further back in the call tree, until we get to inform the user.

I don't see any corresponding `free()` calls for these allocations.  Please don't leak memory.

No comments on the performance right now - deal with correctness first.

Answer (score 0):

More simple to execute it faster could only be worth, when changing the logic.
For instance ensuring that the fields `a` and `b` are ordered, so `check` is not needed.

### Use aliases

`check` can be simpler by using aliases (pointer to a variable/field).

```
int check(Node **F, int a, int b){
    Node **temp = F;
    while (*temp != NULL){
        if (temp->b == a && temp->a == b) {
            Node *removal = *temp;
            *temp = temp->next;
            free(removal);
            return 1;
        }
        temp = &(*temp)->next;
    }
    *temp = createNode(a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

Here temp starts having the address of the head, and then always the address of a `next` field.

A linked list of course is not optimal to check for (b, a). Already keeping the list in order would make it almost twice as fast:

You could insert in the middle after comparing (a, b):

```
    Node *insertion = createNode(a, b);
    insertion->next = *temp;
    *temp = insertion;
```

### `addResult` at the end is costly

Keep the results reversed and add in front, or doubly linked, or maintain a `tail` pointer/alias.